# GHEX Find ascii

Tags: text-editor

I installed GHEX on Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to do a search for ascii text. However, the Find window only allows hex entry. I don't see a way of searching for ascii. I tried uninstalling GHEX and reinstalling, but no joy. This is with GHEX version 3.18.4. Any suggestions on fixing this? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to with Ctrl+F then in the right window type in what you are looking for.

Comment: When that 'Find Data' window comes up, there's no way to enter Ascii. Only Hex. I think there are supposed to be radio-buttons in that window to select Hex or Ascii, but the buttons aren't there. It's like there was something not installed (a dependency ?) when GHEX was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running GHEX, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the Find window.

[image]

[image]

Click in the right window, then start typing what you are looking for (You may have to press the left arrow to remove the period):

[image]

Then click on Find Next and it should find what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: Ok, that was easy. I just started using Ubuntu this week. It's different than a Mac! Thanks.